# Select a File based on Expected Name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open a file based on a name that is only partially complete in VBA. Here is an example:

I want to pull a file with the name: "MMM B2 06222018"

The file will always be located in "C:\Myfile\"

However, these two files are saved in "C:\Myfile\":

"MMM B2 06222018 Updated" - Updated at 10:00

"MMM B2 06222018" - Updated at 9:00

What I want is for the macro to pull the most recently updated file that has the name "MMM B2 06222018" within the file name, but that name may or maynot be the complete name of the file. In this case, the "MMM B2 06222018 Updated" is the file I want pulled because it includes all of the "MMM B2 06222018" name, AND it is the most recently saved file.

```
FileDateTime(file_path) 'I was thinking of using this to compare the file save times. 
'But I can only use this if I have a file name.
```

What is a good way of analyzing the partial file name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function GET_LATEST_FILE(strFolder As String, strWildCardStart As String) As String

Dim d As Date, fld as Object, f As Object

d = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)

With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fld = .getfolder(strFolder)
    For Each f In fld.Files
        If f.Name Like strWildCardStart & "*" Then
            If f.datelastmodified > d Then
                d = f.datelastmodified
                GET_LATEST_FILE = f.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next f
End With

End Function
```

Use this like so

`GET_LATEST_FILE("C:\Workspace\Dummy Data","Sample")`

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

A less powerful way to do this, without FileSystemObject, is to use `Dir`:

```vb
Function GetLatestFile(ByVal FolderName As String, ByVal FileName As String) As String
    GetLatestFile = "" 'Default to blank

    'Declare variables
    Dim sTestFile As String, dTestFile As Date, dLatest As Date

    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> "\" Then FolderName = FolderName & "\" 'Add final slash if missing
    If Len(FileName) = Len(Replace(FileName, "*", "")) Then FileName = FileName & "*" 'Add wildcard if missing
    dLatest = DateSerial(1900, 0, 0) 'Default to 0

    sTestFile = Dir(FolderName & sTestFile) 'First file that matches the filename, if any
    While Len(sTestFile) > 1 'Loop through all files until we run out
        dTestFile = FileDateTime(FolderName & sTestFile) 'Get Created/Modifed Date
        If dTestFile > dLatest Then 'If new file is newer
            GetLatestFile = sTestFile
            dLatest = dTestFile 'Store date
        End If
        sTestFile = Dir() 'Calling Dir without any arguments gets the next file to match the last filename given
    Wend
End Function
```